# Как задать размер массива внутри структуры с помощью переменной?

Tags: c, gcc, arm

Пытаюсь создать структуру и хочется размер массива внутри неё задавать при инициализации структуры. Пробую написать что-то вроде вот этого:

```
struct data
{
    uint8_t buffsize;
    uint8_t data[buffsize];
    uint8_t counter;
}d;
```

но компилятор ругается (*error: 'buffsize' undeclared here (not in a function)*). Структуру объявляю не внутри функции, нужно чтобы она была видна из любого места программы. Можно ли как-то это сделать средствами языка С? Или в Си нельзя задавать размер массива с помощью переменной?

Comment: Нельзя. В случае структуры в динамической памяти (получаете вызвав malloc()/realloc()) можно смоделировать подобное поведение, если массив будет последним членом структуры.

Comment: То о чем говорит @avp, называется flexible array member.

Answer (score 3):

Если структура физически находиться в стеке, то изменить размер уже нельзя. Все локальные переменные занимают место в памяти рядом. Вариант первый: не массив а указатель на память в куче. Вариант два : объект будет только в куче и с последним элементом массивом плавающего размера.

```
// gcc -Wall -std=c11 vararr.c -o vararr
# include <stdint.h>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
// вариант 1
typedef struct datap datap ;
struct datap
{
    uint8_t buffsize;
    uint8_t counter;
    uint8_t * data ;
} ;

// вариант 2
typedef struct datav datav ;
struct datav
{
    uint8_t buffsize;
    uint8_t counter;
    uint8_t data [ ] ;
} ;


int main (  ) {
  // вариант 1
  unsigned  int n = 10 ;
  datap dp = { .buffsize = n , .counter = 0 , 
      .data = malloc ( sizeof(uint8_t[n]) ) } ;
  dp . data [ 5 ] = 5 ;
  printf("sizeof(dp)=%zu\n",sizeof(dp));
  printf("sizeof(dp)+sizeof(uint8_t[%u])=%zu\n",n,
    sizeof(dp)+sizeof(uint8_t[n]));
  free ( dp . data ) ;
  // вариант 2
  unsigned  int m = 10 ;
  datav * const dv = malloc ( sizeof ( datav ) + sizeof(uint8_t[m]) ) ;
  printf("sizeof(dv)=%zu\n",sizeof(dv));
  printf("sizeof(dv)+sizeof(datav)=%zu\n",sizeof(dv)+sizeof(datav));
  printf("sizeof(dv)+sizeof(datav)+sizeof(uint8_t[%u])=%zu\n",m,
    sizeof(dv)+sizeof(datav)+sizeof(uint8_t[m]));
  dv -> buffsize = m ;
  dv -> counter = 0 ;
  dv -> data [ 5 ] = 5 ;
  free ( dv ) ; }
```

Результат :

```
> ./vararr 
sizeof(dp)=16
sizeof(dp)+sizeof(uint8_t[10])=26
sizeof(dv)=8
sizeof(dv)+sizeof(datav)=10
sizeof(dv)+sizeof(datav)+sizeof(uint8_t[10])=20
```

Память массива всегда должна будет находиться в куче. Первый вариант мобильнее. Позволяет менять размеры и быстрее делать операции копирования, переноса. Второй вариант экономнее. Но изменение размеров не позволяет.

Answer (score 1):

Тебе уже норм ответили. Может быть подойдёт такой вариант:

```
#define buffsize 10
struct data
{
    uint8_t data[buffsize];
    uint8_t counter;
} d;
```

Comment: Это же статический массив.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct data
{
    uint8_t buffsize;
    uint8_t* data;
    uint8_t counter;
};

int initData(struct data* d, const uint8_t* data, uint8_t buffsize, uint8_t counter)
{
   d->data = malloc(buffsize);
   if (d->data == NULL)
   {
       return -1;
   }
   memcpy(d->data, data, buffsize);
   d->buffsize = buffsize;
   d->counter = counter;

   return 0;
}

void cleanData(struct data* d)
{
   free(d->data);
   d->data = NULL;
}

int main()
{
   struct data d = {0, NULL, 0};
   uint8_t data[] = {9, 8, 7, 6};
   initData(&d, data, sizeof(data), 1);
   printf("2-th element = '%d' buffsize: %d\n", d.data[1], d.buffsize);
   cleanData(&d);

   return 0;
}
```